# Renault r-link multimedia system on android. How tenable developer mode?

Tags: android, navigation

Multimedia system works on android interface by tomtom. A someone knows how to enable developer mode in this device? Or connect adb to install the application?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to do that. The Multimedia system is not designed to install new developed applications on unless it is done by Renault and it should be installed trough the Renault Store.